# What is the best way to check multiple has_many associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to check if any of a set of `has_many` associations of a Ruby Class has, at least, one item.

Currently the method `in_use?` is written this way:

```
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :destination_day_items
  has_many :user_bookmarks
  has_many :attachments
  has_many :notes
  has_many :notifications 
  has_many :expenses

  def in_use?
    destination_day_items.any? ||
      user_bookmarks.any? ||
      attachments.any? ||
      notes.any? ||
      notifications.any? ||
      expenses.any?
  end
end
```

I think that adding a local variable may prevent a lot of repetead calls if this method is called a few times.

```
def in_use?
  @in_use ||= destination_day_items.any? ||
        user_bookmarks.any? ||
        (...)
  
  @in_use
end
```

But I still feel it's not the best approach.

My question is: Does anyone know a better idea on how to implement this using "The RoR Way"?

Comment: What is the use case for `in_use?`. It's possible it makes more sense to add a flag to the table to mark what is and is not in use.

Comment: I can make an one liner for you like `[:destination_day_items, :user_bookmarks, ...].any? { |meth| self.public_send(method).exists? }` I also don't think you should use instance variable to store the result as it will be cached when the model instance is created. So you might get incosistencies.

Best idea is looking at the **counter cache** way.

Comment: This will be inefficient if you need to query many Venues. Do you need to query all Venues to see which ones are in_use? How many Venues do you expect to have?

Comment: @Schwern At first this was intendend to check if a Venue is associated to any other of these classes (Bookmarks, Notes, Attachments...) and validate if it's safe to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def in_use?
  # define a relations array
  relations = Venue.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name).map(&:to_s)
  
  # check condition 
  relations.any? { |association| public_send(association).any? }
end
```

Comment: Don't need to define some extra array with association names. You can just use `Venue.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map { |reflection| reflection.name.to_s }`

Comment: And also `public_send(association).any?` is better than `eval("#{association}.any?")`

Comment: Thanks! that's new for me

Comment: I like this solution.

Answer (score 2):

> At first this was intendend to check if a Venue is associated to any other of these classes (Bookmarks, Notes, Attachments...) and validate if it's safe to delete it

You can use [option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent) `:restrict_with_error`. This option causes an error to be added to the owner if there is an associated object

```
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :destination_day_items, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :user_bookmarks, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :attachments, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :notes, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :notifications, dependent: :restrict_with_error
  has_many :expenses, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end
```

Let's assume `venue` has some destination day item and we try to destroy it

```
venue.destroy
```

Output will something like this:

```
BEGIN
  DestinationDayItem Exists? SELECT 1 AS one FROM "destination_day_items" WHERE "destination_day_items"."venue_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["venue_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
ROLLBACK
=> false
```

```
venue.errors[:base]
# => ["Cannot delete record because dependent destination day item exist"]
```

So you can show this message to the user if you need

Another option -- `dependent: :restrict_with_exception`. It causes an `ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError` exception to be raised if there is an associated record

These options work when you apply `destroy` method and don't work when `delete`

Answer (score 1):

As they say, there's only two hard problems in computer science: "Cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors". The cached result can fall out of date if any relationships are added or removed during the life of the object.

Also, associations are cached, so there isn't much use in caching the result. `destination_day_items` will only query the database once during the life of the object. However, the cache is not always properly invalidated if the relationships change.

You could add a [counter_cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) to all the associations, then it only has to query the cache number, but see above.

---

Instead of a query for each association, you can increase performance by doing it in a single query.

```
def in_use?
  left_joins(:destination_day_items)
    .left_joins(:user_bookmarks)
    ...
    .where.not(destination_day_items: { venue_id: nil })
    .or( UserBookmarks.where.not(venue_id: nil )
    .or( ... )
    .exists?
end
```

The upside is this query will always get the correct result. The downside is it will always run the query. You could cache the result, but see above.

The real advantage is this can be turned into a scope to search for all in-use venues efficiently.

```
scope :left_join_all_associations(
  left_joins(:destination_day_items)
    .left_joins(:user_bookmarks)
    ...
)

scope :in_use, -> {
  left_join_all_associations
    .where.not(destination_day_items: { venue_id: nil })
    .or( UserBookmarks.where.not(venue_id: nil )
    .or( ... )
}
```

And you can query for those which are not in use with a [left excluding join](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

```
scope :not_in_use, -> {
  left_join_all_associations
    .where(
        destination_day_items: { venue_id: nil },
        user_bookmarks: { venue_id; nil },
        ...
    )
}
```

I'm not 100% sure I got the Rails queries right, so here's a [SQL demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5754fa92742010ae2a7d3d97fbfc4681).

Comment: Yes!  This really needs to be done in SQL, as you show.  Nice use of scopes too.